# Does rails support mysql json data type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm aware that in rails we can use a text data type for columns in mysql that we want to save hashes or array to it, where rails serialize the hash in yaml format and save it in the column.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, Hash
end
```

However if I need to perform some search on this column, I have to load all records and de-serialize all the hashes, and use ruby to search within the hashes. So is there a way to tell mysql to search within the hashes and return matched records ? I think this is not supported with normal yaml serialization as it is just a text, so does rails support mysql json data type or any other solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like Rails 5 should have support for the MySQL JSON data type natively. There is a pull request here [#21110](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21110) that describes it a bit.

And it looks like you'll be able to add this to your `create_table` or `change_table`:

```
create_table :json_data_type do |t|
    t.json :settings
end
```

Comment: how about Rails 4.2.x ?

Comment: Appears that it isn't in 4.2: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21110#issuecomment-166488468

Comment: For Rails 4.x, you can use this gem which backports the JSON native type. https://github.com/saveriomiroddi/json_on_rails