# How to assign array to Mysql column in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have one PostgreSQL table which I want to transform to MySql in my Rails app. Main thing is that ***gateways*** column won't transform into an 'array' column.
It looks like this in schema.rb:

```
create_table "settings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "gateways", default: [], array: true
    t.integer "name"
    t.integer "lastname"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

When I run this migration(after installing MySql gem):

```
class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :settings do |t|
      t.integer gateways, array: true, default: []
      t.string :name
      t.string :lastname
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I got, in my schema.rb, table which hasn't ***default: []*** and ***array: true*** values:

```
create_table "settings", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "gateways"
    t.integer "name"
    t.integer "lastname"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And if I want to add values for gateways in console:

```
>Setting.first.gateways = [1,2,3]
```

I always get nil as a result

```
>Setting.first.gateways
>nil
```

I tried also with serialize :gateways in my Setting.rb model but that also don't work

Any ideas?

Edit: It's not same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409820/add-an-array-column-in-rails) question because it is an explanation for PostgreSQL database, not MySql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an array column in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409820/add-an-array-column-in-rails)

Answer (score 3):

That would have worked for Postgres - but [MySQL does not have a native array type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) (at the time of writing).

It does [have JSON columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769941/does-rails-support-mysql-json-data-type) which can be used to store arrays. Or you can create a separate table and model for gateways and just join it like any other association.

[serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) is an old hack that uses a varchar/text column. It encodes the attributes contents as YAML and stores the resulting string. Its not appropriate here.

> Keep in mind that database adapters handle certain serialization tasks
>   for you. For instance: json and jsonb types in PostgreSQL will be
>   converted between JSON object/array syntax and Ruby Hash or Array
>   objects transparently. There is no need to use serialize in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The way things like that are done is with **serializing** the array. You can try [ActiveRecord::Base.serialize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class). The serialization is done through YAML.

To do so, you must specify this with a call to the class method **serialize**. This makes it possible to store arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects without doing any additional work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(preferences: { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

In your case, you can try as

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :gateways, Array
end
```

Comment: hmm it is turned now into an array, but when I want to add array of integers I get an error: `ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch (can't dump gateways: was supposed to be a Array, but was a Integer. -- 0)`

Comment: You need to explicitly tell rails to expect for an array

Comment: This error raised when unserialized object’s type mismatches one specified for serializable field. So check the type of your object.

Comment: Change your column's datatype to text.